# JToggleButton - how to get selected state?

Tags: java, swing, frame, jtogglebutton

I'm making a BMR calculator and one of my panels gives the user an option to change how they wish to enter their height, from cm to ft/inches.

Here's the block of code that deals with said panel.

```
    // Height JComponents
    heightLabel = new JLabel("Height:");
    heightCMField = new JTextField(4);
    heightFTField = new JTextField(3);
    heightFTLabel = new JLabel("ft");
    heightINCHLabel = new JLabel("inch");
    heightINCHField = new JTextField(3);
    cmButton = new JToggleButton("cm");
    feetButton = new JToggleButton("feet");
    heightPanel.add(heightLabel);


    if (cmButton.isSelected()) {
        heightPanel.add(heightCMField);
    } else if (feetButton.isSelected()) {
        heightPanel.add(heightFTField);
        heightPanel.add(heightFTLabel);
        heightPanel.add(heightINCHField);
        heightPanel.add(heightINCHLabel);
    } 

    heightPanel.add(cmButton);
    heightPanel.add(feetButton);
```

My problem is, when I press the kg or cm button, the text fields do not appear so I'm thinking I've used isSelected() wrong somehow.

An image of how this appears is below. You can see that no text fields appear even when feet is selected. What can I do to fix this?

[image]

Comment: A [toggle button](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) is either selected or not selected.  Your GUI looks like the buttons should be regular JButtons.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc I want to group these like radio buttons, so that I have one on as default and I can switch between them. Is that possible with toggle buttons?

Comment: *"I want to group these like radio buttons,"*  Use a `JRadioButton` (in a `ButtonGroup`)!  Further, the field for `Weight:`, `Height:` and `Age:` should each probably be a `JSpinner` with a `SpinnerNumberModel`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I prefer the toggle button look; is there no way I could make them work like radio buttons? I've managed to group them together so that only one can be selected at the same time, but it doesn't detect when I switch from cm to feet or vice versa. Also, I'll look into JSpinner and SpinnerNumberModel.

Comment: *"I prefer the toggle button look"*  That might be relevant if you are the only user of the app., but in that case the problem becomes too specialized for me to care about..

Comment: Even if I do change it to JRadioButton, the issue persists, i.e. the labels/fields don't update.

Comment: @Ftahir192: It's possible to group toggle buttons like radio buttons, but the code required is so long and advanced, there;s no way I can describe all of the necessary code in 30,000 characters (the limit of an answer).

Comment: I think I managed to do it (albeit not sure if correctly). I just created a buttonGroup and to that button group I added cmButton and feetButton, and set cmButton to the default true.

Comment: kgButton = new JToggleButton("kg", true);
lbButton = new JToggleButton("lbs");
ButtonGroup weightGroup = new ButtonGroup();
weightGroup.add(kgButton);
weightGroup.add(lbButton);

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a listener:

```
cmButton.addActionListener(event->{

    /**
     * Code to show heightCMField.
     */
});

feetButton.addActionListener(event-> {

    /**
     * COde to show heightFTField and heightINCHField 
     */
});
```

And if you are using `JToggleButton`, I suppose you want to use just one ToggleButton that switches your GUI. So if thats the case, delete `cmButton` and `feetButton`. And add only one new ToggleButton that does it all.

```
JToggleButton switchButton = new JToggleButton();
switchButton.setText("cm");  

switchButton.addActionListener(event->{

    if(switchButton.getText().equals("feet")) {

        switchButton.setText("cm");
        /* Code to show heightFTField and heightINCHField */
    } else if(switchButton.getText().equals("cm")) {

        switchButton.setText("feet");
        /* Code to show heightCMField */
    }
});  

You can also go for `ItemListener`.
```

Comment: Thanks for this, trying to get my head around it. I think I'll stick with 2 toggle buttons for now - what would I replace event-> with? Cheers

Comment: I can't seem to get any of this working and I'm not sure why. http://pastebin.com/ABxdT6fV is my current code, any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: event-> remains as it is. Your code needs to goto comment section.

Comment: Whats wrong with pastebin? I tried your code as above to no avail, can't seem to get anything to work in terms of actionListeners.

Comment: I should add, the actionListener is registering the toggle selection, but the items just aren't being added to the panel for whatever reason.
`code`feetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         System.out.println("blah1");
         heightPanel.add(heightFTField);
      heightPanel.add(heightFTLabel);
      heightPanel.add(heightINCHField);
         heightPanel.add(heightINCHLabel);
          }
      });`\code`